# How do I remove javascript tag 'type="text/javascrip"' on html code in PHP

Tags: php, html

I wish to remove `'type="text/javascrip"` inside this code :

```
  <img id="banlink" class="w-100" src="block_images_9.jpg" alt="Homepage Banner"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="epto.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(window).ready( function() {
var m = document.createElement("div");
....
```

How to make it in PHP ? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: What have you done so far, where do you fail?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear, I do not fully understand what you want to do. Please elaborate.

You can have javascript inside of php as follows:

```
<?php
   echo '<script>
           $(window).ready( function() {
           var m = document.createElement("div");
           .... 
         </script>';
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
   echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="epto.min.js"></script>';
?>
```

You can also reference your javascript files as

```
<script src="epto.min.js"></script>
```

without the type="text/javascript" as stated in your question.